# How can i make a custom dos command like cp/md/ren etc

Tags: c#, command-line

i am using c# language to build a console application. My target is i have to build a custom command like "do pfizer.text" and it'll create a file "phizer.text" on desktop.

I know i can do this with existing commands but i want to make my custom command ( "do" in this case).

Can anyone tell me how to do this ??? I will prefer c# language as solution language.

Thanks,
-seoul.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Finding the desktop? Using command line args? Writing a command line app? What code have you gotten so far?

Comment: Before preceding, consider this example: You have to delete a file in d:/input/output named example.text folder using command prompt..

You'll write in command prompt: del d:/input/output/example.text 

Pretty simple, right ?? Then which part i asked ??

Ans: I asked how to create a command like "del", which will perform the task as i'll make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create your own console application with the name of command. Place this application on any folder included in `%PATH%` OR add your folder path to the `%PATH%`.

To check current paths -

1. Open cmd
2. Type `path`

To add new path -

1. Open cmd
2. Type `set path="%path%;c:\mypath\"`

Comment: I have no idea about %PATH% .......Suppose, i created application as "example.exe" on "c:/programs" directory. Then what i need to do ??

Answer (score 3):

The command line (not DOS for a long while now) will search for executables or scripts in all folders defined on the `%Path%` system variable. By adding the path of your program to that variable you can start it from anywhere.

You can find these variables at the System Properties dialog:

[image]
<sub>(source: [vlaurie.com](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/graphics/envvar.gif))</sub>